# Getting an exception like "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource." while trying to set the itemsource of a child DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid and another DataGrid nested inside the parent DataGrid. I need to set the ItemSource of the child DataGrid as a property of the parent DataContext. I already tried to use RelativeSource for the child itemsource to get the parent datacontext.

xaml code

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row ="1" x:Name="Grid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=md,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Categogy" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path =CateName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Characterictics" Width="300">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
               <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.list, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DataContext.list.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
               </DataGrid>
             </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel

```
Model m = new Model();
m.CateName = "CategoryName";
m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name="XX", Value="00"});
m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
md.Add(m);

Model m1 = new Model();
m1.CateName = "CategoryName1";
m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
md.Add(m1);

list = new ObservableCollection<Characteristics>();
list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
```

The Characteristics class has properties Name and Model.

Now, I am getting exception like "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

I am not sure where I am doing wrong?
Can someone please help me to correctly bind the child dataGrid Itemsource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row ="1" x:Name="Grid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=md,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Categogy" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path =CateName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Characterictics" Width="600">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Edit:If you prefer to use list from the datacontext of window
please change the nested datarid as

```
 <DataGrid   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding list,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Model> _md = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        public ObservableCollection<Model> md
        {
            get { return _md; }
            set { _md = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Characteristics> _list;
        public ObservableCollection<Characteristics> list
        {
            get { return _list; }
            set { _list = value; }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            Model m = new Model();
            m.CateName = "CategoryName";
            m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "test Name", Value = "00" });
            m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "TEst name1", Value = "00" });
            m.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
            md.Add(m);

            Model m1 = new Model();
            m1.CateName = "CategoryName1";
            m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
            m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
            m1.list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });
            md.Add(m1);

            list = new ObservableCollection<Characteristics>();
            list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "vali", Value = "00" });
            list.Add(new Characteristics() { Name = "XX", Value = "00" });

        }      
    }

    public class Model
    {
        private string cateName;
        public string CateName
        {
            get { return cateName; }
            set { cateName = value; }
        }

        private List<Characteristics> _list = new List<Characteristics>();

        public List<Characteristics> list
        {
            get { return _list; }
            set { _list = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Characteristics
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private string value;

        public string Value
        {
            get { return this.value; }
            set { this.value = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

for the nested DataGrid place `DataGridTextColumn` into a `<DataGrid.Columns>` tag

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

otherwise DataGridTextColumn is interpreted as Item and causes error with itemsSource

and also fix bindings, they don't need to use parent DataContext

Comment: Thanks! Adding <DataGrid.Columns> helped to avoid the exception. But the Binding of the child datagrid is sill not working. I used <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}"> as suugested by you. But no data is populated in the grid.

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, is Category (CateName) is the 1st column binding correctly? please show what is a dataContext of parent DataGrid and `md` in particular. also make sure that you have public *properties* with getter/setter everythere, not *fields*

Comment: Category is showing properly in the 1 st column. I have bound parent datagrid with a public property named md defined in my viewmodel. The Model  I am using is like: public class Model
    {
        public string CateName
        {
            get;set;
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Characteristics> _list = new ObservableCollection<Characteristics>();
        public ObservableCollection<Characteristics> list
        {
            get { return _list; }
            set {
                _list = value;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, `list` binding should be fine with such `Model` class. is `Name` a property in Characteristics? please check Visual Studio Output window for any messages about binding errors

Comment: Surprisingly the same number of rows are generated in the child grid as the number of items in the list. But I cannot view any data. Am I missing something silly?

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, please show `Characteristics` class code. also try `DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ` on a child datagrid - it should generate columns for all properties and show all values

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just figured out the Name was declared as a field not a property. Changing that solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @SudiptaSaha, I remarked about properties/fields before. if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted